# How to compute the unit outer normal at the point in a curve?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Given a smooth closed curve $f(x,y)=0$, How to compute the unit **outer** normal at each point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ in the curve?

Comment: Can we assume that $f$ is a *simple* closed curve?

Comment: OK,we can assume so

Comment: If that's the case just orient the curve in the counterclockwise direction and then the outward normal is $\mathbf n = (\dot y, -\dot x)$.  If for some reason you must have the curve oriented in the clockwise direction, then the outward normal will instead be $-\mathbf n$. In the non-simple case, I'm not even sure I know what outward normal means.